# Reducing image height and width by 50% but image size on disk remains the same

Tags: java, android

I am trying to reduce the size of the image by reszing its length and width but it stays the same size in megabytes sometimes its even larger even though its only half as big.

```
String compressPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test2.jpg";
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(path);
Bitmap fullSizeBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    fullSizeBitmap, 
    (int)(fullSizeBitmap.getWidth()*0.5), 
    (int)(fullSizeBitmap.getHeight()*0.5), 
    true
);

FileOutputStream mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(compressPath);
resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, mOutputStream);
```

What's the problem? Do I have to lower the quality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Bitmap's Android doc:

> quality   Hint to the compressor, 0-100. 0 meaning compress for small
>   size, 100 meaning compress for max quality. **Some formats, like PNG
>   which is lossless, will ignore the quality setting**

Your original input is JPG, but you are outputting it to PNG. Since JPG will always have quality degradation that introduce artifacts, making the generated PNG files larger when converted. Try saving it as JPG with 80-100 quality instead.

Also, in my tests compressing to PNG take 2-5x more time than compressing to JPG, due to PNG compression is done in software and JPG in hardware. So for most images it's probably better to compress to JPG.

Comment: How am I outputting it as  PNG?

Comment: your code: `resized.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, mOutputStream);`, try replacing `Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG` with `Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG` and see if it helps.